# Can I use a 25 meter LED stripe with a single power adapter?

Tags: power-supply, led, safety, led-strip, rgb

I have 5 stripes of 5m length and 300 RGB LEDs (type 5050) each. One LED consumes about 20 mA at 12 V. Therefore, my whole 25m setup would use about 30 A.

[image: 5050 RGB LED stripe]

Is it safe to connect the 5 stripes series and powering one end with a 30 A power adapter? I wonder whether the small traces on the PCBs can handle that. If that's not possible, what would be a safe setup?

Comment: You are best off actually measuring the actual current that each 5m length consumes.  I highly suspect that your current is significantly less than you are thinking.  In strips like this, there are *usually* 3 (or more) LEDs in series to allow operation from higher voltage at lower current.

Comment: In fact, looking at the picture you show, that is exactly the case.  Notice the cut line is between the 3rd & 4th LED from the end.  I can't make out the value of the middle resistor but I'm guessing that the 150 Ohm resistors are for the green and blue LEDs.  Assuming about 3.2V per led, we get 12V - 9.6V = 2.4V divided by 150 Ohms equals about 16mA per group of 3 LEDs per color.

Comment: @DwayneReid It's 331 Ohm for red and 151 Ohm for blue and green respectively. 16mA per 3 LEDs per color is 48mA per 3 LEDs, which would still give me 25 A for my 1500 LEDs, right? At the moment, I can't measure the actual current, but I'll do the next days.

Comment: @danijar - A 331 resistor is actually 330 ohms, that is, 33 x 10 ^1. Likewise a 151 is actually 150 ohms - same arithmetic. "16 mA per 3 LEDs" is 16 mA per color, since 3 LEDs (1 red, 1 green, 1 blue) are needed to produce a color. So your 1500 LEDs will produce 500 "color units", and at 16 mA / color will need .016 x 500, or 8 A.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast Thanks for the clarification. However, there actually are 3 color units every 5 cm segment, thus 1500 in total. So it's 24 A unfortunately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the comments I left with your question.

Personally, I would power each 5m strip with its' own cable coming back to your controller or power supply.  Note that the common lead has to handle the sum of the currents for each of the colors and thus should either be a larger conductor *or* multiple conductors in parallel.

Comment: I want to mount the stripes around the room near the ceiling, so I'd have to lay cables down from the ceiling every 5 meters which would be a bit annoying. Is there a way to estimate how much stripes I can power in a row? Having only two power supplies would be easier to hide in the room.

Comment: After reading your answer again, I have a second question. The LEDs have a shared anode, and I plan to mix colors by using a PWM signal for the kathodes of the channels. How can I use multiple power supplies then? I guess that would only work with synchronized PWM signals or did I get it wrong?

Comment: Use one power supply for each 5m string if you have to.  Just be sure to connect the negative lead from each supply to your controller.  The controller doesn't know or care if the individual LED strips have separate power supplies so long as they are all working.  Do note that the PWM controller has to be rated to handle the full current of ALL of the LED strips.

Comment: What I've done in terms of getting wire to all of the LED strips is to run the wire behind the LED strips.  This is usually done when the place is being built and it was easy to have the carpenters provide a space behind the surface where the LED strips mount to hide all of the wires.

Comment: Alright, since I'll install the LEDs all around the room, they'll form a circle. The largest distance from the power supply will be 12.5 m then. Can I power this using a single 8 A power adapter then?

Comment: About PWM - you only need a single 12 volt power supply to drive all 3 colors. About running long wires - much will depend on the thickness of the  wires you use. The common 12 volt (anode) wire has to handle a worst-case 8 amps continuous. See any on-line wire size calculator, but also size the wire for 15 amps. The reason is that the wire is hidden behind the strips, and will get hotter than if it were in the open. The last thing you want to do is melt the wire insulation. The 3 color (cathode) wires can be sized for 1/3 the current of the common wire.

Comment: I don't know how much current all of your LEDs will consume.  I did calculate that the green and blue consume about 16 mA per group of 3 LEDs but I have *no* idea how many LEDs are in each string.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: We were talking about how he could use multiple supplies if the power supply that he wanted to use was too small.  I explained that he could split up the load over several supplies.

Comment: Altogether, there are 500 red LEDs with 330 Ohm series resistors each, 500 green ones with 150 Ohm series resistors and 500 blue ones with 150 Ohm series resistors.

Answer (score 2):

Powering 25 meters of continuous Flexible Circuit Board, from a single power connection, will not work. There are heat and voltage droop issues from that much current over high resistance copper tape.

The higher the current and the longer the led strip, the lower the voltage at the far end will be. Accordingly, it will result in dimmer leds the farther down the cable we go. This is slightly noticeable on a single 5M run, a 25M run will probably not even light up at the end.

You will need to run multiple parallel regular 18 or 16 awg cable to different parts of the led strip.

Comment: One question, would it somehow damage the stripes or would the light just be dimmer? I'll get some awg cables but I'd like to test this first.

Comment: Too much heat can cause the cable to unglue and the leds and resistors to desolder, or worse. 25A at 12v is 300 watts you are putting through fpc meant for alot less.

Comment: Thanks to @Dwayne Reid, I expect the current drawn from the 25 m stripe to be around 8 A. Does that change the situation?

Comment: That's not right. A typical 300 led per 5M roll RGB strip uses 3 leds per segment per color. That's 100 segments per color. That's ~20mA per segment so 100 *.02A = 2 Amps per color. That's 6A at 12v when full white (72 Watts). Per 5 Meters. So your initial current usage was right. 30 Amps, at full white, taking ideal numbers and no voltage droop into account. Actual numbers will be less due to actual resis tor value, or that the resistors chosen give ~18mA at 12v, or the length of the cable causing voltage droop from the copper resistance.

Comment: Ah,  he said about 8A per color,  so 24A at full white,  all three colors on. That's close to my calculations with ideal numbers.

Comment: Each segment has 3 5050 led packages, and 3 resistors. Each 5050 has 3 led diodes. So each segment has 3 led diodes, per color. 9 diodes total. 8A per color for 25 meters means 24 Amps total.

Comment: Positive. Simple math. 16 - 20 mA per series circuit (color), 3 series circuit per segment 100 segments per 5 meter roll, 5 rolls (25 meters).

Comment: Okay, I see. I cleaned up some of the comments. Moreover, I had the chance to test the stripes today. You're right, that it's slightly noticeable on a 5 m strip and more than one stripe looks annoying. I think I'll buy a 300 W computer power supply and lay cables to feed the stripe every 5 m.

Comment: @danijar and since your are powering it from both sides/middle of every 5M, even that slight color difference will go away.

Comment: Yes. One more thing: Won't I still have a voltage drop when I use a single power supply and a long 18 awg behind the stipe?

Comment: The bigger the cable, the smaller the resistance. You will but it would be negligible.

Comment: Thanks. Can you elaborate on this a bit, please? I used an online voltage drop calculator and it says I'll lose 5 V with a 10 m 18 awg cable that serves half the current (12 A).

Comment: Because you should be feeding it at multiple points. Each run of the 18awg would only carry a few amps each. See http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/powering-17-meters-of-rgb-led-strip-worried-about-voltage-drop-and-wire-size/70726#70726

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would your advice be to use those LED strip amplifiers to feed in extra power supplied or use one large (desktop computer) power supply and feed it at multiple points laying some cables?