# Voltage loss over wire

Tags: voltage, current, wire

I need to run 12v across 30 feet of 18 guage wire.  The device on the other end consumes 2 amps.

I have a 12v power supply (rated 3A) and I want to ensure the device on the other end gets the full 12v.

I found this post [voltage loss calculation](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/58700/how-to-calculate-voltage-drop-over-and-power-loss-in-wires) but I'm not clear on something.  If my power supply can put out 3A and the device only needs 2A, does that mean there will be no voltage loss?  (there is no sense wire)  Will the full 12v arrive but there will be current loss?

I'm missing something basic here...

---

UPDATE:

I found 18 guage copper wire has resistance of 6.385 Ohm/1000 feet.  so 6.385 * 60feet/1000feet * 2 amps = .76v loss.

From the comments it's apparent that voltage loss is unavoidable.  So if I need 12v at the other end of the wire, I will need a power supply with 12.76v output (or adjustable).  I already purchased a 12v switching power supply from ebay today for $8 - perhaps i bought too soon.  Can these power supplies be adjusted (crack open the case)?   Do 12v power supplies really put out exactly 12v?  (Or do they put out 13v assume loss on wire, etc)

Comment: There are online calculators for this.

Comment: There are also power supplies with a "sense" line, which is feeding back the actual voltage and enabling the PS to adjust it.

Comment: " I want to ensure the device on the other end gets the full 12v" go to your local hardware store and ask for a spool of superconducting cable................. or go with @Eugene's answer.

Comment: I'm afraid I misplaced my spool of superconducting cable, so copper.  The formula would sure be simpler otherwise.

Comment: Its just ohms law..... R per foot * length * amps. times  2 if its a single return.

Comment: OK - I updated the question and fixed link.  Hopefully its clearer now what I'm looking for.  (Confused on concept)

Comment: How much current the PSU can put out is unimportant as long as it's greater than the draw. The voltage drop is equal to the current draw times the wire resistance, as Ohm's Law states.

Comment: Its not about what the power supply can supply.. its about how much resistance the wires add that drop the voltage along the way at the load current.

Comment: If you have 12V PS, there is *no way* of having 12V on the other side unless you find your superconductor...

Comment: OK - so I'll update the question in the hopes of finding an answer (for anyone else searching)

Comment: Don't forget the current travels both ways...

Comment: Is there a reason you cant put the 12V supply at the far end?

Comment: Yes - the device is mounted high up on a wall so I don't want to run a 120v line up there.  I was trying to make life easier for myself

Comment: But 18 guage DC is somehow easier???

Comment: In principle what you are asking is impossible all cables drop voltage though in practice I doubt there is an issue. How much current do you need and why? No product supplies an exact nominal voltage and none require one.  There are tolerances to work within.  Advise load and PSU requirements we can advise if possible and cabang needed.

Comment: Trevor_g: Are you saying 18 gauge wire is a problem?  or just that lower gauge = lower resistance.

Comment: No I'm saying if you have to run heavy wire up there anyway, why not run AC up there and put your power supply local to the device.

Comment: With a 2 amp load, I would choose a bigger gauge wire. But that's just me. Just going to 16g wire will reduce your voltage loss to less than .5v, and 14g gets you to .3v

Comment: since you do not wish to run line voltage to the device, do the next best thing ... run 16V DC to the device and use a dc-dc converter to generate the 12V DC at the device

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my power supply can put out 3A and the device only needs 2A, does that mean there will be no voltage loss? (there is no sense wire)

I'm afraid not but the loss that does occur at 2 A will be less than that for 3 A.

> Will the full 12v arrive but there will be current loss?

Current loss implies a partial short-circuit between the feed and return wire - e.g., poor or leaky insulation - and this is unlikely with modern insulating materials. As explained above the voltage will drop.

---

If you have an option, you could transmit the power at a higher voltage and reduced current and step down to 12 V at the load. AC won out over DC due to the ease of voltage transformation to minimise transmission line losses.

---

> I don't know the exact current draw of the device yet, but I'm told 1 - 2 A is most likely. Its a computing device so it might be sensitive to the full 12v.

It is close to 100% certain that the computing device will use either 5 V or 3.3 V internally for the logic. The 12 V supply will be regulated down to the required voltage. There may be some other components such as display or backlight but these are most likely to be tolerant of a volt variation in voltage. i.e., The device requires 12 V nominal.

If there is no adjustment pot accessible from outside there won't be inside a sealed unit.

Comment: I don't know the exact current draw of the device yet, but I'm told 1-2A is most likely.  Its a computing device so it might be sensitive to the full 12v.  Can you comment on the ADJ of something like this: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Universal-12V-24-360W-2-5-10-20-30A-Switching-Power-Supply-Driver-for-LED-Strip/222316447845?hash=item33c317c865:m:mhU16LOJEyhyChwdfXTojWQ  would that allow adjustment UPWARDS, or only trim (downwards) of the voltate?  Assuming this is a common feature...

Comment: See the update.

Comment: OK - I've ordered another power supply with +/15% output adjustment, so that should solve my problem.  I suspect you are right that the 12v is regulated down but I can't be sure so better safe than sorry.  I'll just have to eat the $8 loss on the power supply coming from china, and buy another

Comment: @TSG be careful here. Adjusting up just makes the voltage higher when you are drawing less current which can be worse than being too much drop. Also if you are sending other signals to/from the remote  device the voltage drop changes on the common return line can be a nightmare. This issue may be larger than you imagine.

Comment: Trevor_g: I don't follow- if I increase the voltage output won't that solve the problem?  My current draw should be unchanged.  All other signals are running over a (USB) connection with active repeating designed for 30 feet - so that part should be ok.  What is the 'common return line'

Comment: @TSG What Trevor means (I think?) is that if your current consumption is not constant, the voltage will jump accordingly.

Comment: Eugene: I'm showing my lack of knowledge here, but, wouldn't the switching PSU supply constant output voltage regardless of current draw?  So if I adjust up 0.76v at the PSU, should the other end of the cable always have 0.76v more regardless of current draw?

Comment: It will supply constant voltage, but the voltage drop on the cable will depend on the actual current running there, so the voltage on the load. So for instance, if at some instant the current draw will be near 0, the voltage on the load will be close to the one of PS.

Comment: OK that makes sense.  I suppose that's why they sell PSU's with a 'sense wire'.  I'll have to check ebay for such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

This is what you actually have with a 2A load and 30ft of 18 Guage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjXb50.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As you can see, voltage is dropped over both the wires leaving you with 11.27V at the load assuming the load is constant.

However, loads are seldom constant, and that 6 ohms can easily, and randomly, increase to hundreds of ohms depending on what the load is doing. At that point the current falls and the voltage seen across the load becomes much closer to the supply voltage. As such, increasing the supply voltage to compensate for the worst case drop can cause over-voltage issues instead. The latter can be much more damaging.

---

The other issue you need to worry about is if you are transmitting signals between the local and remote device. Because of the voltage drop along the wires there is now a difference in reference levels at each end of the wire.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpRRDQ.png)</sup>

In the schematic above the low level digital signal is being sent back from the remote device, however, that signal is at a higher reference level than the local device. As such the local device sees a higher than normal low level on the wire. If that difference is high enough the logic may not work.

If the power currents are switching, the power switching noise, caused by the changes in the voltage drop, will be coupled directly into the signal line. If it is not too bad, that may be acceptable on a digital signal, but is a killer on an analog signal.